# Flex DropDownList fires focus out on scroll when used in datagrid item editor

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, drop-down-menu, itemeditor

I have a data grid with a custom item editor that displays a DropDownList component. When I click the scroll bar in the component, it is firing a focus out event on the list, which is causing itemEditEnd to fire. I can't figure out why the list is not keeping focus, or how to make it keep focus. I'm using Flex 4.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't reproduce your problem but the solution probably involves listening to an event on the scrollbar and stopping its propagation. That should prevent the datagrid from getting the event and dispatching its own itemEditEnd event.